# how to hold a Class<T> reference in a class?

Tags: java, generics

I am noobish as far as generics is concerned . Plus java's confusion compile error "cannot convert from java.lang.Class to java.lang.Class" doesn't help

Here is my class

```
public class XMLParser<T> {

private static XMLParser reference=null;
String rootNode;
String requiredNode;
List<String> members;
Class<T> targetClass;


private XMLParser()
{

}

public static XMLParser getInstance()
{
    if(reference==null)
        reference= new XMLParser();
    return reference;
}


public <T> T  parse(Class<T> target, String inputString, String rootNode, String requiredNode,
        List<String> members) {

    this.rootNode=rootNode;
    this.requiredNode=requiredNode;
    this.members=members;
    this.targetClass=target; //compile error
```

I dont understand whats going on here . I want to hold a global reference to the input "target" , because this "target" would be used in a lot of methods in the class .

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the type variable declared in your `parse` method

```
public <T> T  parse(Class<T> target, String inputString, String rootNode, String requiredNode,
     // ^ get rid of this
```

That `<T>` bit declares a new type variable that shadows (has the same name) the type variable declared in the class name expression. The type variable `T` here and the one declared at class level are unrelated.

Comment: Thanks Sir , this was it . Can't select this as the right answer as yet . In ten minutes it says .